# SQL Server 2008 R2 marked for unload due to memory pressure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I noticed the following error message on a development server that I'm working on.  Can anyone tell me what this means? AppDomain 21 [mssqlsystemresource.sys[runtime].21] is marked for unload due to memory pressure

Answer (score 0):

Memory pressure can be caused by a lot of different things. Start by running the Best Practice Analyzer. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15289

Answer (score 0):

It means that an AppDomain in the SQL Server .NET runtime environment (yes, you can activate that ant then write things in C#, i.e. custm data types) has been marked for unload because SQL Server is running out of memory / was asked to release memory.

This can point to an awful clueless configuration, it can point to a machine being overloaded, it can also point to nothing - your server may just have temporary memory pressure i.e. because it is patching and all works normal all the time. A running and needed AppDomain will not be unloaded, so this also sort of implies that the AppDomain is CURRENTLY not being utilized. Your admin should be skillfull enough to validate whether or not the server is doing what it does in a manner that is acceptable.